# React.js: How to send a link to the props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I need to use the props in the function and promise. How to do it?

```
let a = this.props.func // method
let b = this.props.func // method
function(){
   b // not method
   a // undefined
   this.props.func // undefined
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current issue is that you are using an anonymous function. Anonymous functions do not inherit `this` from the scope above it. It automatically assigns itself to the `window` object (or `global` if using node). In a React Component, it might return `undefined`.

```
(function(){
  console.log(this === window || this === undefined) //true, in a React Component
})()
```

You have two solutions (but one is much better)

**1. Use `bind`, an ugly solution**
`bind` will create a new copy of the function, where `this` is assigned to be whatever you want it to be. You can `bind` to the scope above it (which is your React Component).

```
(function(){
  console.log(this !== window && this !== undefined) //true, in a React Component
}).bind(this)() //`this` in `bind` is your React Component's `this`
```

**2. Use an arrow function, much preferred**
Arrow functions do not have their own `this`. It accepts `this` from the scope above it. This does *not* occur in a normal `function`.

```
(() => {
  console.log(this !== window && this !== undefined) //true, in a React Component
})()
```

Ultimately, this is the direct answer to your question:

```
() => {
   b 
   a
   this.props.func
}
```

I am surprised that `this.props.func` did not throw an error in your original example. Maybe you decided to omit that part.

Answer (score 0):

A lambda keeps it `this` referenced to the `this` you are looking for, so doing

```
() => {
  this.props.func //is a method
}
```

Also, `let` only works in the same scope, by executing the function you are creating a new scope, change the `let`s by `var`s, and the method is retained inside the new scope.